# mkdir is making two folders using uniqid()

Tags: file, upload, mkdir

I am making a subfolder inside the user id folder with mkdir.

```html
$uid = $_SESSION['id'];<br>
$uaids = uniqid();<br>
$_SESSION['uaid'] = $uaids;<br>
mkdir("uploads/".$uid."/".$uaids, 0777);<br>
```

the problem I am having is that it is inserting two folders at the same time. each with a different uaids.

[folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQ0eg.jpg)

the first folder inserted is the one I am echoing out.

[echoed uniqid to see what is going on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q28T1.jpg)

How do I prevent this?

Comment: I really wish someone would help me out with this is been months and I still can not figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue.

turns out the page was loading twice.  I put everything into a form post submit. problem solved.